# Wrong response onPostExecute

Tags: android

i'm doing a login system on an android app, when i enter a wrong account the `onPostExecute` method returns the right fail message, but after when i enter a existant account and the login is correct its still the same fail message and i don't why !

**these is my  `onPostExecute` method :**

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final String res) {
        //LoginTask = null;
        //showProgress(false);

        try {
             jObj = new JSONObject(res);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            if (jObj.getString("code").equals(1)) {

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), HomesActivity.class);
                //Lançer l'activité
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

            } else {
                //password.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
                //password.requestFocus();
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                builder.setTitle("Error !");
                builder.setMessage("The information entered is incorrect.\nPlease try again!")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: try this `jObj.getString("code").equals("1")` way..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be it:

`if (jObj.getString("code").equals(1))`
"1" is not the same as 1 :)
Try this:
 `if (jObj.getString("code").equals("1"))`

P.S. You didn't include json format so I'm taking a stab in the dark.